# Efficiently remove common patterns from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I am trying to write a function to calculate how likely two strings are to mean the same thing. In order to do this I am converting to lower case and removing special characters from the strings before I compare them. Currently I am removing the strings '.com' and 'the' using `String.replace(substring, '')` and special characters using `String.replace(regex, '')`

```
str = str.toLowerCase()
         .replace('.com', '')
         .replace('the', '')
         .replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
```

Is there a better regex that I can use to remove the common patterns like '.com' and 'the' as well as the special characters? Or some other way to make this more efficient?

As my dataset grows I may find other common meaningless patterns that need to be removed before trying to match strings and would like to avoid the performance hit of chaining more `replace` functions.

Examples:

Fish & Chips? => fish chips

stackoverflow.com => stackoverflow

The Lord of the Rings => lord of rings

Comment: can you share few examples?

Comment: Why not store your common/meaningless patterns in an array then convert them to a character set regex pattern before doing the replace, so you can just replace matches to that pattern with blanks?

Comment: You can use regular expression with OR between the strings.

Comment: like: str.toLowerCase().replace('.com|the', '')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect the replace calls to a single one with a rexexp like this:

```
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\.com|the|[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
```

The different strings to remove are inside parentheses () and separated by pipes |

This makes it easy enough to add more string to the regexp.

If you are storing the words to remove in an array, you can generate the regex using the `RegExp` constructor, e.g.:

```
var words = ["\\.com", "the"];
var rex = new RegExp(words.join("|") + "|[&\\/\\\\#,+()$~%.'\":*?<>{}]", "g");
```

Then reuse rex for each string:

```
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(rex, "");
```

Note the additional escaping required because instead of a regular expression literal, we're using a string, so the backslashes (in the `words` array and in the final bit) need to be escaped, as does the `"` (because I used `"` for the string quotes).

Comment: Good answer, but as I said in my comment I would store the strings in an array to begin with so no changes are needed to the base replace pattern.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That was my point; there's no need to include all of the character sets in the actual replace method call.

Comment: @t-j-crowder, right you are. Edited out the capture group.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That is what I was suggesting for the OP, and what Orr's answer didn't include. I was saying the answer would be better using an approach like this. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JohnClifford: With you now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this question is that im sure you have a very concrete idea in your mind of what you want to do, but the solution you have arrived at (removing un-informative letters before making a is-identical comparison) may not be the best for the comparison you want to do.

I think perhaps a better idea would be to use a different method comparison and a different datastructure than a string. A very simple example would be to condense your strings to sets with `set('string')` and then compare set similarity/difference. Another method might be to create a Directed Acyclic Graph, or sub-string Trei. The main point is that it's probably ok to reduce the information from the original string and store/compare that - however don't underestimate the value of storing the original string, as it will help you down the road if you want to change the way you compare.
Finally, if your strings are really really really long, you might want to use a perceptual hash - which is like an MD5 hash except similar strings have similar hashes. However, you will most likely have to roll your own for short strings, and define what you think is important data, and what is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will have a look into them. I am storing the original strings in my database before I make these changes to them, so it won't be a problem if I want to change my method later.